# how to make voice chat using external ip c#

Tags: c#, .net, voip

I want to make voice chat using external ip over Internet using any protocol but using external ip and local ip using c# I have no problem in voice just my problem how to send and receive buffer

```
private Socket r;
private Thread t;
r = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Voice_In));
#region Voice_In()
        private void Voice_In()
        {
            byte[] br;
            r.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(this.textBox2.Text)));
            while (true)
            {
                br = new byte[16384];
                r.Receive(br);
                m_Fifo.Write(br, 0, br.Length);
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Voice_Out()

        private void Voice_Out(IntPtr data, int size)
        {
            //for Recorder
            if (m_RecBuffer == null || m_RecBuffer.Length < size)
                m_RecBuffer = new byte[size];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, m_RecBuffer, 0, size);
            //Microphone ==> data ==> m_RecBuffer ==> m_Fifo
            r.SendTo(m_RecBuffer, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(this.textBox1.Text), int.Parse(this.textBox3.Text)));
        }  

        #endregion
```

Comment: ok I will take about it next time

Answer (score 0):

Well if your only issue is to network data between two ip addresses, you should just focus on the network part. Do you want to use WCF or TCP directly? In the second case, System.Net.Sockets namespace has classes like TcpClient, TcpListener, UdpClient...

Comment: ok i will use TCP i see many example using udp and socket but using local ip like 192.168.1.3 and if i tried to call my friend in another city using his external ip from www.whatsmyip.org failed how can i make it ?

Comment: ok lets see the which work on local ip and port for receiving voice and another for sending voice

Comment: textbox2 recieve port number
textbox1 recieve ip
textbox3 send ip